# row number in ascending order for MySQL

Tags: mysql

This question asked a lot on Stackoverflow but I'm facing something different issue with it.

```
SET @rownum = 0; 
SELECT DISTINCT doc.id, 
                doc.created_date, 
                ( @rownum := @rownum + 1 ) AS rownumbers 
FROM   document AS doc 
       INNER JOIN document_type_master dt 
               ON doc.document_type_id = dt.id 
ORDER  BY doc.id ASC;
```

Above query gives me following output.

```
id      created_date         rownumbers
5664    2014-06-05 07:23:40  1
5665    2014-06-06 06:37:34  2
5666    2014-06-06 10:25:56  3
5667    2014-06-06 10:33:39  4
5668    2014-06-06 11:28:28  5
```

If I change `ORDER  BY doc.id ASC` to `ORDER  BY doc.id DESC` then output is

```
id      created_date         rownumbers
6364    2014-11-11 17:57:04  691
6363    2014-11-11 11:09:49  690
6362    2014-11-11 10:58:34  689
6361    2014-11-10 17:39:47  688
6360    2014-11-10 16:59:53  687
```

I experimented few things and find that if I remove `DISTINCT` from my query then `rownumbers` is started from `1,2,3...` in case of `ORDER  BY doc.id DESC`.

```
id      created_date         rownumbers
6364    2014-11-11 17:57:04  1
6363    2014-11-11 11:09:49  2
6362    2014-11-11 10:58:34  3
6361    2014-11-10 17:39:47  4
6360    2014-11-10 16:59:53  5
```

I also tried giving order for `rownumbers` like `ORDER  BY doc.id DESC, rownumbers ASC` but not worked for me.

I want `rownumbers` value should always be in `ASC` order no matter I use `DISTINCT` or not.

---

**Update**

@Barmar is correct but If I use `rownumbers` in `WHERE` clause like

`rownumbers between 1 and 5` then is shows an error `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'rownumbers' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` processing is done *after* generating all the rows in the result. So first it assigns all the `rownumber` columns by processing the data in whatever order it is in the database, then it reorders it in reverse.

The reason this only happens when you use `DISTINCT` is because that requires it to generate all the results first so it can remove all the duplicates. Without `DISTINCT`, it can take a shortcut and perform the ordering on the original table data. However, while this generally works as expected, it isn't guaranteed.

To get the result you want, you need to put the `ORDER BY` into a subquery:

```
SET @rownum = 0;
SELECT x.*, ( @rownum := @rownum + 1 ) AS rownumbers 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT doc.id, 
                    doc.created_date
    FROM   document AS doc 
           INNER JOIN document_type_master dt 
                   ON doc.document_type_id = dt.id 
    ORDER  BY doc.id DESC) AS x
```

To refer to rownumbers in a WHERE clause, you need another level of subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT x.*, ( @rownum := @rownum + 1 ) AS rownumbers 
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT doc.id, 
                        doc.created_date
        FROM   document AS doc 
               INNER JOIN document_type_master dt 
                       ON doc.document_type_id = dt.id 
        ORDER  BY doc.id DESC) AS x
    ) AS y
WHERE rownumbers BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

or you may be able to use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT x.*, ( @rownum := @rownum + 1 ) AS rownumbers 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT doc.id, 
                    doc.created_date
    FROM   document AS doc 
           INNER JOIN document_type_master dt 
                   ON doc.document_type_id = dt.id 
    ORDER  BY doc.id DESC) AS x
HAVING rownumbers BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

But I've seen some weird behavior when trying to use `HAVING` with aliases that come from variables like this, apparently because of shortcuts that MySQL takes.

Comment: if I use `rownumbers` in where clause like `rownumbers between 1 and 5` then it says `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'rownumbers' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Is there any other way then creating multiple alias

Comment: `HAVING rownumbers BETWEEN 1 AND 5` not worked as expected but creating multiple alias works fine. thanks.